# How to Replace a single, unknown, index in a 2d list in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

How would I be able to replace a single index in a 2d list if we don't know what value is currently in that location?

Initially, i thought

```
twoDList[0][0].replace('A')
```

would work; however, it does not. So what is the proper way to replace an index in a 2d list in python?

Comment: `    #Craft a 2d board
    board = [['.' for a in range(rowNum)] for b in range(columnNum)]


    #Iterate through each row
    for i in range(rowNum):
        #Iterate through each column
        for j in range(columnNum)::
                    board[i][j].replace('A') `  rowNum and columnNum are user inputed constants

Comment: I don't understand if you want to insert A and you don't care about the old value or you want to only replace a value the value in 2d list if it is A?

Comment: I would like to replace the old value with A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.replace` does not do in place replacements since strings are immutable, rather it returns a copy of the string. make sure to set the new value to the item:

```
tw0dList[0][0] = 'A'
```

Comment: i still get the error `TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: i wasn't even thinking, i relooked at your question and it looks like you dont want to be using replace. correct me if im wrong but do you just want the value at `twodlist[0][0]` to be 'A'? i editted it to do that